# Probability event example

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need few examples of probability space ant event (this event belongs to probability space) to show that equations are incorrect in general
$$\mathbb{P}(B|A)+\mathbb{P}(B|\overline{A})=1$$  $$\mathbb{P}(B|A)+\mathbb{P}(\overline{B}|\overline{A})=1$$

I have no idea...

Comment: I have no idea. I can't find examples..

Comment: hmm... can you think something about coins, dice, or cards? Try out a few things. Edit to include what you have tried to improve the post?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the probability that you have red hair. Let's say the probability that you have red hair given that you're Irish is 1/10, and the probability that you have red hair if you're not is 1/50. Then clearly, 1/10+1/50 does not equal 1. For the second equation, consider throwing a die. The chance you roll a 6 given that you've rolled a 5 is 0, while the chance that you haven't thrown a 6 given that you haven't thrown a 5 is 4/6. Clearly the probabilities do not sum to one in this case either.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
I will let you check the following.

Assuming $\overline{A}$ means the complement of $A$, then we have
\begin{align}
& \mathbb{P}(\text{second die roll is }1\mid \text{first die roll is }1)+\mathbb{P}(\text{second die roll is }1\mid \text{first die roll is not }1)\neq 1.\\
&\mathbb{P}(\text{roll two 1s}\mid \text{second roll is 1})+\mathbb{P}(\text{roll at most one 1}\mid \text{second roll is not 1})\neq 1.
\end{align}